# Hide JQuery menu button in the header

Tags: jquery, button, mobile, menu, header

I have wrote the following page:

[CLICK HERE](http://www.brainandbytes.com/mobileapp/ricerca2.php?s=accetto)

What's the way to hide the grey button under the 3 lines icon on the right header?

This is the code of the header:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="min-height: 60px;">
  <img border="5" src="logo2.png" alt="Logo" style="border-color:#dd0000;float:left;display:inline"/>
  <a id="bars-button" data-theme="a" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconshadow="true" data-shadow="true" data-corners="true" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a" href="#navpanel">
   <span class="ui-btn-inner">
      <span class="ui-btn-text"><img src="images/smico.png"></span>
   </span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove background from this class

```
.ui-btn-up-a {
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    // remove this background
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(241, 241, 241)) repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(47, 62, 70);
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

or update it as `background: none`

To remove border also

```
.ui-btn-up-a {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.ui-btn-inner { 
   border: none;
}
```

This is setting the background from your 3 lines menu on right header

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. I found the class and change it in .ui-btn-up-a {
 border: 1px solid #dd0000 /*{a-bup-border}*/;
 background: none /*{a-bup-background-color}*/;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #2f3e46 /*{a-bup-color}*/;
... live the rest

Comment: Can you inspect the element in the browser inspector, i tried there its working. May be some css is overriding it. As per inspector it is present in themes/MobileApp.css

Comment: Can be... I found a solution changing so: .ui-btn-right { background: none; display: none; border: none !important; }. Now I need only to delete the border...

Comment: What you can do is make your css more specific .ui-header .ui-btn-up-a {} then your specific one will be picked irrespective of fact when the other one is getting loaded

Comment: Yes, with your last update it's much more better! Now there is only a bottom thin border (round corner) but its very difficult to see... Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept the answer ir it has solved your question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I found a quick solution adding this code in a  in the file header:

```
      .ui-btn-right { background: none; display: none; border: none !important; }
```

Now, as you can see is visible a very thin border and I have no idea how to hide or delete it.

Comment: Remove border from this .ui-btn-inner under ui-btn-up-a